# O365 Group Calendar and SharePoint List relationships

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, office-365-groups

I'm working on a solution that requires scheduling meetings(Teams), take notes from that meeting, such as issues raised, attendees, minutes all in a structured manner. In essence, the scheduled events need to have related sub items.

Using a SharePoint Calendar as a container (Parent) with sub list items should work but then I dont believe a SharePoint calendar can schedule Teams meetings, therefore considering an O365 Group Calendar. - (Please correct me if I'm wrong and there are alternatives). But from SharePoint I cant lookup Group Calender's.

So my question is how can I tie a Group Calendar to sharePoint lists, in a 1 to many relationship. i.e. create calendar events, then be able to create sub-items in lists that link to the calendar event and visa-versa ?

One option I was considering is to somehow sync a group calendar to a sharePoint calendar/list. Not sure if this is possible.

I would consider creating a webpart if required as a last resort.
Hope someone can assist me on this.

**UPDATE:** One important requirement is that the solution needs to be replicated easily, around 200 cloned solutions are needed for various projects. So I'm looking for a solution that is easy to deploy with little final configuration. Finally, the solution needs to lend itself to modification for each project, should project requirements change in the future. Originally I thought PowerApps was the way to go but this will not allow for flexibility needed. Then I thought SharePoint solution with several webparts, which can be cloned by site scripts may work as it allows flexibility. But with this option I cannot interface with a Group Calendar and create events with sub-items (as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) to schedule your events with the M365 Group calendar.

Unless you need to provide visibility to the calendar for users who are not members of the Group, I wouldn't use a SharePoint List.

Comment: I'm planning to use ootb group calendar to schedule events. I only need to provide visibility to members. As per my OP, I need a way to record activities (such as tasks), so don't understand why you suggest I dont use SP lists. How else would I accomplish it?

Comment: Planner would be my "modern" suggestion. Outlook Meetings will also be receiving meeting outcomes. See https://myignite.microsoft.com/sessions/c8878f6d-076b-4d24-a15a-4406a3d36d19.

Comment: Hi Trevor, I looked at myignite link but couldn't find any concrete info about how outlook can provide structured attachements, unless I missed it. I've updated question to give context. I think, if possible, create an automation script that creates a container (either a SPsite, Group, Team). Then when a Calendar event is being created, somehow in the body of the message include a dynamic link to template date (i.e. SP List) - Sounds like a lot of work though and risky.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s possible to tie a group calendar to some SharePoint lists.

As a workaround, you could add meeting events with information you want in the group calendar. Then add group calendar web part in the modern page to view meeting events.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm aware that its possible to add notes in the meeting itself but its unstructured. Ideally, the notes need to be sortable like a list and categorised.
The Group Calendar webpart is not intuitive, it lacks the ability to look like a normal calendar and I cannot add/modify any events. Is there a third party calendar that has these features?

Comment: You could view the calendar via Outlook or even embed it in the site via an iframe to see the calendar view.

Comment: Depend on your requirement, you could use SharePoint calendar list, then connect it to outlook.